# Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for HttpHeaders: (?)

Tags: angular, http-headers, authorization

getting an error while passing a header authorization in `get` request

```
 compiler.js:486 Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for HttpHeaders: (?).
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:486)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (compiler.js:15706)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (compiler.js:15541)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getInjectableMetadata (compiler.js:15521)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getProviderMetadata (compiler.js:15881)
    at eval (compiler.js:15792)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getProvidersMetadata (compiler.js:15752)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:15320)
    at JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.js:34413)
```

this is the code I implemented in `auth.service.ts` and subscribing it in methods

```
getContent() {
    const headerOption = new HttpHeaders ()
    .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + btoa(new Util().getData('token')));

    return this.http.get('/path/to/my/api', {headers: headerOption});
  }
```

It's preventing the UI to render, please help me with it!

Comment: I think the correct way is using .append, like `const headerOption = new HttpHeaders ()` `headerOption.append(....)`

Comment: even i tried that, it gives same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try append method. If you look at HttpHeaders api, you will find this:

```
append(name: string, value: string|string[]): HttpHeaders { 
  return this.clone({name, value, op: 'a'}); 
}
```

which means that you return a clone of HttpHeaders instance. In your case try this:

```
getContent() {
  const headerOption = new HttpHeaders ();
  headerOption = headerOption.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + btoa(new Util().getData('token')))

  return this.http.get('/path/to/my/api', {headers: headerOption});
}
```

hope this helps!